# Showing Results using child when clicking a button in parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am Trying to build a simple trivia quiz using React and i am stuck on as to how to show the results when the user clicks "Check Answer" Button. I need to change the colors of label reflecting correct and wrong choices.

```
props ={ 
questions: arr[str] 
answers: arr[arr[str]] 
correct-answer: "str" 
}

export default function QuestionPage(props){let [showResults,setShowResults] = React.useState(false)let Questions = []
    
    // create 5 questions using the data from props
    function getQuestions(){   
        for (let i =0;i<props.questions.length;i++){
            Questions.push( 
            <Question 
                key= {nanoid()}
                question = {props.questions[i]}
                answers = {shuffle(props.answers[i])}
                correct_answer = {props.correct_answers[i]}
                showResults = {showResults}
            /> )
        }
        return Questions
    }
    function TotalScore(){
        Questions.forEach( (value,index)=>{
            console.log(value,"\t",index)
        })
        //get all inputs using DOM and check 
    }
    
    return (
        <main>
            {getQuestions()}
            { showResults && <TotalScore />}
            <button onClick={() => setShowResults(true)}>Check Answers</button>
        </main>
    )

}
```

I was hoping to change the background color of labels inside the input field I have created for answering the questions :

Red if user selected the wrong option 
Green if correct.

I can handle the css bit of coloring, just need to understand "how to implement the passing of command from button in parent component down to child component" functionality in React.

Below is the code for `Question.js` Component

```js
export default function Question ({question,answers,correct_answer,showResults}) {

    const [selected,setSelected] = React.useState({
        selected: ""
    })
    
    function handleChange(event){
        console.log(event.target,"\t",selected.selected)
        setSelected( {
            selected: event.target.value}
            )
    }
    return(
        <div className='question-container'>
            <h4>{question}</h4>
            <div className='answers-row'>
    
    
                <fieldset>
                <input 
                    type="radio"
                    id = {answers[0]}
                    name = {question}
                    value = {answers[0]}
                    onChange = {handleChange}
                    checked = {selected.selected === answers[0]}
                />
                <label htmlFor={answers[0]}>{answers[0]}</label>
                <br />
                
                <input 
                    type="radio"
                    id={answers[1]}
                    name = {question}
                    value =  {answers[1]}
                    onChange = {handleChange}
                    checked= {selected.selected === answers[1]}
                />
                <label htmlFor={answers[1]}>{answers[1]}</label>
                <br />
                
                <input 
                    type="radio"
                    id={answers[2]}
                    name = {question}
                    value =  {answers[2]}
                    onChange = {handleChange}
                    checked= {selected.selected === answers[2]}
                />
                <label htmlFor={answers[2]}>{answers[2]}</label>
                <br />
    
                <input 
                    type="radio"
                    id={answers[3]}
                    name = {question}
                    value =  {answers[3]}
                    onChange = {handleChange}
                    checked= {selected.selected === answers[3]}
                />
                <label htmlFor={answers[3]}>{answers[3]}</label>
                <br />
            </fieldset>
            </div>
        </div>
    
    )

}
```

Answer (score -1):

In your code, you are maintaining the state ie. the answer selected by the user, on each `Question` component. However, when the user clicks the button `QuestionPage` components re-render so do its children. The `getQuestions()` will be invoked and components will be created again and states will again be initialized to the default value ie `""`.

Read this https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html. The example given here is similar to what you are trying to do.